# How do we get nested object type in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, graphql, relay

I have the following typescript interface:

```
UserInfo: {
     user: {
        options: ReadonlyArray<{
            values: ReadonlyArray<{
                value: string | null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to access the options how do I get it.
I tried like below but it doesn't work for me

```
type options = ScreenQuery["UserInfo"]["user"]["options"];
```

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ because? what was the error or wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `ScreenQuery` is in your snippet but if `UserInfo` is indeed an interface this works ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoEkQwPbIDeAUMsgK6ZQBcRpZyeADmMHiOrQEoRwAm7ADYBPAIJQocYQB4SDBgDc4g8hE7Ie-IWIlTZ9eWSUqItdGCigA5sgA+yEOUGCA3AYYBfAHzvv9D8QBxGDCTCjMrOzoyAC8aFQ4+ADaAOSU0CkAuqkRbBxZbkA)):

```
interface UserInfo {
  user: {
    options: ReadonlyArray<{
      values: ReadonlyArray<{
        value: string | null;
      }>
    }>
  }
}

type options = UserInfo['user']['options'];
```